# How can I use "the quantity of" naturally in an IELTS essay?

Tags: grammar

**Context: In IELTS tests, they give us a chart showing information about the data for something over a period of time and ask us to analyze it and make comparisons where relevant. I can actually use "the amount of" or "the number of" but it is advisable to use a wide range of vocabulary to show your lexical knowledge. "The quantity of" seems to be a good alternative, but I don't know how to use it naturally.**

A native speaker once told me that "the quantity of" is more usually used with uncountable nouns than countable nouns. That sounds like a simple rule to follow, but I also asked this question in another English forum and they thought maybe there was no one solid rule for this case, so maybe determining if each specific structure is natural or not is a better approach?

If that's the case, could you categorize the following structures (you can just use the numbers) into two groups - "Unnatural" or "Natural"?

(1) The quantity of money spent a year on mental health issues by an average person started at $240 in 2000. => unnatural.

(2) The quantity of people... started at... => unnatural.

(3) The quantity of time ... started at... => unnatural.

(4) The quantity of [a type of time unit] ... started at... => unnatural.

(5) The quantity of [a type of material goods] ... started at ... => natural.

(6) The quantity of [a type of liquid] ... started at... => ?

(7) The quantity of [a type of grain] ... started at... => ?

(8) The quantity of [a type of metal] ... started at... => ?

(9) The quantity of [a type of cooking ingredient]... started at... => ?

(10) The quantity of [a means of transport] ... started at... => unnatural (since it's countable => a number of is better?)

(11) The quantity of [a type of container] ... started at... => unnatural (since it's countable => a number of is better?)

(12) The quantity of [a type of chemical] ... started at... =>

(13) The quantity of [a type of energy (calculated by the kilowatt-hour or something)] ... started at... =>

I've already categorized some structures according to my knowledge. I don't really trust myself, but I still want to leave them there to show what I thought in the past.

Here is a categorization example:

- Natural: 1,2,3,4,5,6,7
- Unnatural: 8,9,10,11,12,13

It would help me so so much if you could help. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: If you look at order sheets from companies from which you are buying someting, for example, you will see QTY as a column heading standing for quantity purchased or ordered.

Answer (score 0):

This [NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20quantity%20of&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-GB-2019&smoothing=3) suggests that in the UK the use of 'quantity' may be declining. A glance at [Google Books (British) 1965-2019](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22the%20quantity%20of%22&lr=lang_en&sca_esv=587583771&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1965,cd_max:2019,lr:lang_1en&tbm=bks&ei=hW1tZeCcN76zhbIPp7SnqAM&start=100&sa=N&ved=2ahUKEwig88Hjj_WCAxW-WUEAHSfaCTU4UBDy0wN6BAgOEBc&biw=1320&bih=720&dpr=1.09) suggests it is increasingly confined to formal contexts, including the proceedings of the Houses of Parliament.

Among other things, it is applied to Government debt, to radioactivity, vegetation, grain, hops, cotton, information, gold, saltpetre, hydrogen, components, comparisons, wine, malt, matter, energy, physical contact, antibiotic use, critiques, waste paper and bisyllabics in North Lappish.

In the UK *Quantity* isn't applied to human beings or to animals (except perhaps extremely small ones). We generally talk about a *number* - or a large/small number - of these. We also use 'many': Were there many people there? Yes - a great many people.

Nor is 'quantity' applied to *time*. We speak about the *length* of time (a long time; how long something is) or say *how much* time (it takes/there is/you have/you need) to do something; or *how many units* of time (it takes/there are/you have/you need) to do it.

You could use Ngram to research "a good [or a great] deal of", "a good [or a great] many", "[quite] a few", and, the informal "a load of" or "loads of".
For example:

Are there a great many bisyllabics in North Lappish?
Yes. There are loads of them. There are loads and *loads* of bisyllabics in North Lappish!"

Comment: It depends on context. Businesses use QTY on order forms for widgets all the time. That is not declining...As for animals: what was the quantity of chickens sold?

Comment: @Lambie: [quantity of chickens](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22quantity+of+chickens%22%3A.uk&client=firefox-b-d&sca_esv=587717745&ei=qQBuZfeQD8SS8gLn_ozIBQ&ved=0ahUKEwi3idqMnPaCAxVEiVwKHWc_A1kQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22quantity+of+chickens%22%3A.uk&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiGiJxdWFudGl0eSBvZiBjaGlja2VucyI6LnVrMggQIRigARjDBDIIECEYoAEYwwRIx1VQyQhY7idwAXgAkAEAmAFgoAHCA6oBATa4AQPIAQD4AQHCAg4QABiABBiKBRiGAxiwA8ICCBAAGIAEGKIE4gMEGAEgQYgGAZAGAw&sclient=gws-wiz-serp).

Comment: @Lambie: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22quantity+of++widgets%22%3A.uk&client=firefox-b-d&sca_esv=587717745&ei=MgJuZfb7O8u6hbIPju6nkAs&ved=0ahUKEwj23LnInfaCAxVLXUEAHQ73CbIQ4dUDCBA&uact=5&oq=%22quantity+of++widgets%22%3A.uk&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiGiJxdWFudGl0eSBvZiAgd2lkZ2V0cyI6LnVrMgUQIRigAUjcNlDzEFjfMnACeACQAQCYAb8BoAHzBKoBAzIuM7gBA8gBAPgBAcICDhAAGIAEGIoFGIYDGLADwgIIEAAYgAQYogTCAggQIRgWGB4YHeIDBBgBIEGIBgGQBgM&sclient=gws-wiz-serp.

Comment: @ Lambie: I've edited my answer to say "in the UK". Thanks.

Comment: just: quantity of site:.uk Loads of it.

Comment: @Lambie: quantity of chickens site:.uk doesn't find any chickens. Likewise with 'widgets': no widgets found.

Comment: quantity of site:.uk produces loads of results. Searching those results for 'chickens' results in 'none found'. Searching them for 'widgets' ditto.

Comment: quantity of on site:.uk https://www.google.com/search?q=quantity+of+site%3A.uk&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS1077US1078&oq=quantity+of&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqBggAEEUYOzIGCAAQRRg7MgkIARBFGDkYgAQyBwgCEAAYgAQyBwgDEAAYgAQyBwgEEAAYgAQyBwgFEAAYgAQyBwgGEAAYgAQyBwgHEAAYgAQyBwgIEAAYgAQyBwgJEAAYgATSAQkzNTQ4ajBqMTWoAgCwAgA&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8